# How can I fix following TS2345 error in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am going to fix the error that was caused developing react js

```
//router/routes.tsx file
interface AppRoute {
  path?: string;
  index?: boolean;
  element?: JSX.Element;
  nestedRoutes?: AppRoute[];
}
export const dashboardRoutes: AppRoute[] = [
  {
    path: PRIVATE_ROUTE_PATHS.home,
    element: <PanelLayout />,
    nestedRoutes: [
      { index: true, path: PRIVATE_ROUTE_PATHS.home, element: <Dashboard /> },
      { path: PRIVATE_ROUTE_PATHS.contacts, element: <Contact /> },
      { path: PRIVATE_ROUTE_PATHS.contactDetail, element: <ContactDetail /> },
    ],
  },
];

//mian.tsx
import { dashboardRoutes } from 'router/routes';
import useBreadcrumbs from 'use-react-router-breadcrumbs';

const breadcrumbs = useBreadcrumbs(dashboardRoutes); //error
```

Following error caused last line of code:
`TS2345: Argument of type 'AppRoute[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BreadcrumbsRoute<string>[]'. Type 'AppRoute' has no properties in common with type 'BreadcrumbsRoute<string>'.`

Please help me to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. First you need to look at the type of the variable you're using as a parameter.

`dashboardRoutes` is of type `AppRoute[]`.

`useBreadcrumbs` only accepts `BreadcrumbsRoute<string>` as a parameter.

You are just passing the incorrect data type in.

Comment: Please leave me fixed code.

Comment: `const breadcrumbs = useBreadcrumbs([]);` – If you want something more useful, you'll have to provide me more details

Comment: dashboardRoutes is needed variable

Comment: No its not. You CANNOT pass in `dashboardRoutes` to `useBreadcrumbs` because it is not the correct type. No matter how hard you try, you cannot pass in a variable of the wrong type to that function. It will not compile.

Comment: You really need to learn the basics of TypeScript. Just change the type where you declared it. So `const dashboardRoutes: BreadcrumbRoutes<string> = ...`. Without first learning the basics of TypeScript, or type-strict languages, you will fall into many traps that will hinder your ability to write good code, mediocre code, or any code at all. Make sure to learn the basic of TypeScript before moving ahead – it will save you tons of time in the future: [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)